# Getting Excel to return a row which has two values

Tags: database, arrays, excel, lookup

I have a csv file that has all the fixtures of a football League between 2003 and 2012 (this is in Sheet1). I want Excel to return the row containing certain fixtures to my worksheet, i.e. when team A (in cell $B$18) played team B (in cell $D$18) home and away. I have used this array formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$F,SMALL(IF(OR(AND(Sheet1!$C:$C=$B$18,Sheet1!$D:$D=$D$18),AND(Sheet1!$C:$C=$D$18,Sheet1!$D:$D=$B$18)),ROW(Sheet1!2:2)),2))
```

Where Sheet 1 has

```
column B: date,
column C: home team,
column D: away team,
column E: home score,
column F: away score
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Can somebody point out the mistake in my formula?

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer**

I assume you are somewhat familiar with array formulas, it looks like that is what you are using.

I have managed to get this formula to work for me entered as an array formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$F$10,SMALL(IF(((Sheet1!$C$2:$C$10=$B$18)*(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$10=$D$18))+((Sheet1!$C$2:$C$10=$D$18)*(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$10=$B$18)),ROW(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$10)-1),ROW(A1)),F$17),"")
```

Where `F$17` refers to the column you would like to return ie 2 for home team, 3 for away.
I have used a reference so I can copy across four columns and get home and away teams and scores.
Copied down for as many rows as you would expect to be returned.

Comment: Thanks, but really I want to return the array from columns B-F in sheet1 containing all the matches played between team A and team B.

Comment: Updated:=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$F,SMALL(IF(OR(AND(Sheet1!$C:$C=$B$18,Sheet1!$D:$D=$D$18),AND(Sheet1!$C:$C=$D$18,Sheet1!$D:$D=$B$18)),ROW(Sheet1!$C:$D)),ROW(Sheet1!2:2)),2)  , still no luck

Comment: Glad I could help, that was the first time I have actually used an array formula so it was quite interesting. Dont forget to mark this as the correct answer.